# Is there a way to make Visual Studio 2010 auto-completion optional (e.g. keyboard driven)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, autocomplete, intellisense

Visual Studio's auto complete feature is extremely useful but can also be extremely irritating when completing values which are incorrect.

Is there a way to have access to the auto-complete values without having them automatically insert?  For example, hitting Ctrl-Space or some other keyboard shortcut when I'm wanting the automatic insertion would be perfect.

I'd also be curious to find out how others deal with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Tools -> options -> Text Editor -> All Languages (or specific).
2. Uncheck "Auto list members"

Comment: Thank you.  You have no idea how much this has been annoying me.